# Left outer join with duplicate names in two tables

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl, create-table

I am doing left outer join on two tables using 3 columns. All the 3 columns have same name in two table. Given below is the code I am using:

```
CREATE table tmp_hrpu_flag_acct as 
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
  FROM tmp_nrm_hrpu_tb_dd_actv_upd t1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN TMP_NRM_HRPU_TB_CUST_RTD2_Af2 t2
    ON t1.customerid = t2.customerid
   AND t1.client_category = t2.client_category
   AND t1.crs_country = t2.crs_country;
```

I am getting the error

> [Error] Execution (7: 17): ORA-00957: duplicate column name

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

Since you are creating a table, duplicate column names are not allowed. You should specify each and every column and give them an alias:

```
SELECT t1.customerid      t1_customerid
,      t1.client_category t1_client_category
,      t2.customerid      t2_customerid
,      t2.client_category t2_client_category
```

Etc.